# How can I customize server certificate validation when using TLS with Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ssl-certificate

I am attempting to connect a .NET 6 application to a SQL Server 2016 instance that uses a self-signed server certificate. Using the default connection string settings, this results in an error

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
```

The error is technically correct, as the certificate is self-signed and not issued by a trusted authority. Because this is an internal, private database, getting a trusted authority to sign the certificate is not an option. *Edit:* We also don't have an internal CA that's already trusted in our network.

I am aware of the `Encrypt=False` setting, but we would like the connection to be encrypted. I am also aware of the `TrustServerCertificate=True` setting, but that leaves us open to man-in-the-middle attacks, if the attacker also uses a self-signed certificate. Ideally, I would like to customize certificate validation and allow the connection if the certificate thumbprint matches the one I'm expecting.

If this were an HTTP request, I could do the following

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, errors) => {
    if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None) return true;
    if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
        return cert.Thumbprint == "MyTrustedThumbprint";
    return false;
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

This solution avoids man-in-the-middle attacks (because they can't replicate the thumbprint) and it avoids our team from having to install a self-signed certificate onto every machine in our network.

Is there anything similar to `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` within the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` ecosystem? Bonus points if the solution also works with higher-level database access such as Entity Framework or Dapper.

Comment: The best approach, IMHO, would be to generate a cert from your internal CA.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have an internal CA.

Answer (score 1):

> Because this is an internal, private database, getting a trusted authority to sign the certificate is not an option.

That is not true. There are still two paths to getting the cert signed by a trusted authority:

1. Have your server joined to an Active Directory domain named for a public domain you really do control. In this case, you can purchase a certificate from a reputable (trusted) CA vendor that will be accepted by your clients.

   Note this does NOT necessarily mean having your AD domain use the same name as your public-facing services (which is, of course, not recommended); just that it's set to use a domain name that *could* be public, and that you can prove to the satisfaction of a trusted CA that you own this name. You can often pass this check via a combination of a phone call to a number in the WHOIS registry that you actually answer and a set of DNS TXT and CAA records, meaning no server using this domain even has to be reachable from the internet.

   Also note that you're **supposed** to setup AD this way anyway, but I know lots of places did not do as they should, or the AD environment pre-dates this guidance. If that's the case I understand this is a big thing to ask your organization to change. Which brings me to the second path...
2. Run your own CA, where your clients are set to trust the CA. This is fairly straight-forward in AD environments. If you have AD Certificate Services setup properly with your domain, your domain-joined clients **will** trust it as par for the course.

   Unlike the first option, if you don't already have a CA and you can't follow path 1, it *is* somewhat reasonable to expect an organization to get this working in order to support secure communication with the database, because there will be other benefits as well.

If neither of those paths is feasible (ie, the clients will not be part of AD), then you will have to publish the certificate to your clients, so it can be added to their certificate store.

It's worth mentioning that *there is no work-around in client code that will allow you bypass this*. The only alternative is **unencrypted** communication with the database server. This is because the native sql client absolutely will **not** let you customize the certificate check, and Sql Server has been supported by .Net from day one using the native client, such that no one has ever seen a need to make an alternative, whether commercial, open source, or something in between.